# I dont know how to attempt this equation. Should there be isolation or should it be rearranged?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Find the particular solution to the following differential equation,

y′ + 6y  =  x,

satisfying the initial condition  y(0) = 1.

Comment: You should use the method of integrating factors -- do you know it?

Comment: i do but how would you apply it to this question. I believe i am over thinking it

Answer (score 0):

We can use for our integrating factor the exponential of any antiderivative of 6 -- I suggest $\mu(x) = e^{6x}. $ Multiplying both sides by this, we get on the left side $\frac{d}{dx}[ye^{6x}]$ (as we knew we would), and on the right side $xe^{6x}.$ I leave it to you to integrate both sides and rearrange to obtain the general solution. Then you can plug in the values in the initial condition to solve for the constant and get the particular solution.

Comment: okay, that makes sense now! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the differential equation :

$$y'+6y=x\tag{1}$$

and also the associated "homogenous" differential equation :

$$y'+6y=0\tag{2}$$

It's is easy to find a particular solution of $(1)$, namely :

$$x\mapsto\frac x6-\frac1{36}$$

On the other side, the solutions of $(2)$ are given by :

$$x\mapsto Ce^{-6x}$$

where $C$ denotes an arbitrary constant.

So the solutions of $(1)$ are given by :

$$y:x\mapsto\frac x6-\frac1{36}+Ce^{-6x}$$

Now, we have to find $C$ in order to have $y(0)=1$, that is :

$$C=\frac1{36}$$

Finally, the required solution is given by :

> $$y(x)=\frac x6+\frac1{36}\left(e^{-6x}-1\right)$$

Comment: ohh okay, that makes alot more sense then what i originally had it laid out as. Thank you so much!!